# Could you create a folder with the name of a file in a folder with cmd?

Tags: cmd

```
Folder 125121 / file 125121

Folder 125121 / Lix / file 125121
```

I want to create the lix folder after the folder 125121 /

since I use this code to create folders depending on the file name

```
for %i in (*) do mkdir "%~ni"

for %i in (*) do move "%i" "%~ni"
```

but now I have it

```
file 125121
file 111111
file 112222
```

What I look for

```
folder 125121 / lix / file 125121
folder 111111 / lix / file 111111
folder 112222 / lix / file 112222
```

Comment: This will only work if your files have an extension on them.  Otherwise, you would end up with the entries with the same name and you will get "A subdirectory or file BLAHBLAH already exists."

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. [SO] isn't a free script writing service. Own research and code attempts are expected. [Edit] the question to include **your** code in a [mcve]. Your examples are IMO a bit too abstract/unclear. If you want to change text `file ######` to `folder ######` you'll have to parse the names with a `for /f`.

Comment: Well, you want folders `Lix` to be created, but your code does not even mention that name; so what do you expect??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want, but the following should be close:

```
for %%a in (*) do (
  ECHO md "%%~na" 2>nul
  ECHO copy "%%~a" "%%~na\lix\%%~nxa"
)
```

Remove both `ECHO` commands after verifying it does what you want to actually enable the `md` and `copy` commands.